# Prime numbers formed by consecutive numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $x$ be an even number. Suppose that we concatenate it with its successor to form $x (x+1)$ (not multiplication, but concatenation). For example, if we start with $x = 2$, we would get $23$. If we start with $x = 4$, we would get $45$. If we start with $x = 6$ we would get $67$. If we start with $8$ we would get $89$. If we start with $10$ we would get $1011$, and so forth.

Are there infinitely many prime numbers of the form $x (x+1)$?

Comment: Probably yes, but I don't think we can prove this with current knowledge. (I did not downvote.)

Comment: This is definitely beyond the reach of current methods. This is in spirit (and in asymptotic density) similar to the question of existence of palindromic primes.

Comment: Hi, Wojowu! What do you mean with similarity in terms of asymptotic density?